# Break-Point Implementation for Fixed-Point Iteration for System of Equations in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, fixed-point-iteration

```js
const x = new Array(3).fill(0)
const x0 = new Array(3).fill(0)
const er = new Array(3).fill(0)
const C = [1, 1, 1];
for (let j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < C.length; i++) {
        x[i] = C[i] + 1 / x0[i];
        er[i] = Math.abs(x0[i] - x[i])/x0[i];
        x0[i] = x[i];
        if (er[i] < 0.0001){
            break;
        }
    }
}

console.log("x", x, "er", er)
```

My goal is to solve for x, a 1D array, using fixed-point iteration method and insert a break point when each solution converges within 0.0001 tolerance error. Unfortunately, when the first element reaches the desired convergence error limit, it breaks the loop while other solutions are yet to reach.

Is there a better way to implement the break in this case? If I do not include the break and the solutions are displayed below (please note that I have set the parameter C to have the same value so as to better see the crux of this problem).

```js
const x = new Array(3).fill(0)
const x0 = new Array(3).fill(0)
const er = new Array(3).fill(0)
const C = [1, 1, 1];
for (let j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < C.length; i++) {
        x[i] = C[i] + 1 / x0[i];
        er[i] = Math.abs(x0[i] - x[i])/x0[i];
        x0[i] = x[i];
    }
}

console.log("x", x, "er", er)
```